# File .htaccess in Sub Folder (Wordpress inside Laravel)

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have Wordpress apps inside Laravel. This is what it's looks like.

```
public
--article
```

WordPress inside `article` folder. The reason I do this because I want it to access WordPress like this
`{host}/article`

There is issue occured. I can access `{host}/article/wp-login.php`. But when I fill The Login Form out and then send it, I got Laravel `404 Not Found Error Page`.

This is weird because several days ago I can do that, but now error occured.

I think I miss some configurations in the `.htaccess` but I don't know the error.

This is my Laravel `.htaccess` configuration

```
# public/.htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and this is my WordPress `.htaccess`

```
# public/article/.htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /article/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /article/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what error your getting ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul i think I clearly write it down. I got 404 not found error when I send the login form. Technically I got error when I send ```POST``` request.